# Overload resolution with an empty brace initializer: pointer or reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, overload-resolution

I ran into a real-life WTF moment when I discovered that the code below outputs "pointer".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
struct bla
{
    static void f(const T*) { std::cout << "pointer\n"; }
    static void f(const T&) { std::cout << "reference\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    bla<std::pair<int,int>>::f({});
}
```

Changing the `std::pair<int,int>` template argument to an `int` or any other primitive type, gives the (for me at least) expected "ambiguous overload" error. It seems that builtin types are special here, because any user-defined type (aggregate, non-trivial, with defaulted constructor, etc...) all lead to the pointer overload being called. I believe the template is not necessary to reproduce it, it just makes it simple to try out different types.

Personally, I don't think that is logical and I would expect the ambiguous overload error in all cases, regardless of the template argument. GCC and Clang (and I believe MSVC) all disagree with me, across C++11/14/1z. Note I am fully aware of the bad API these two overloads present, and I would never write [something like this, I promise](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/blob/dev/src/corelib/thread/qfutureinterface.h#L179).

So the question becomes: what is going on?

Comment: I found a defect that might be relevant: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1536. I'm not sure if this helps resolve the issue, as it seems unresolved.

Comment: Interestingly, T&& also produces this symptom.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh, this is nasty.

Per [over.ics.list]p4 and p7:

> 4 Otherwise, if the parameter is a non-aggregate class `X` and overload resolution per 13.3.1.7 chooses a single best constructor of `X` to perform the initialization of an object of type `X` from the argument initializer list, the implicit conversion sequence is a user-defined conversion sequence with the second standard conversion sequence an identity conversion. [...]
>
> [...]
>
> 6 Otherwise, if the parameter is a reference, see 13.3.3.1.4. [*Note: The rules in this section will apply for initializing the underlying temporary for the reference. -- end note*] [...]
>
> [...]
>
> 7 Otherwise, if the parameter type is not a class:
>
> [...]
>
> (7.2) -- if the initializer list has no elements, the implicit conversion sequence is the identity conversion. [...]

The construction of a `const std::pair<int,int>` temporary from `{}` is considered a user-defined conversion. The construction of a `const std::pair<int,int> *` prvalue, or a `const int *` prvalue, or a `const int` temporary object are all considered standard conversions.

Standard conversions are preferred over user-defined conversions.

Your own find of [CWG issue 1536](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1536) is relevant, but mostly for language lawyers. It's a gap in the wording, where the standard doesn't really say what happens for initialisation of a reference parameter from `{}`, since `{}` is not an expression. It's not what makes the one call ambiguous and the other not though, and implementations are managing to apply common sense here.